# Elementor conflicts with Ekommart Theme

Tags: php, arrays, wordpress, elementor

I have a problem with elementor and Ekommart wordpress theme , I think there's is a conflict betweed this two , Tried to install the last version of Elementor and Ekommart but this problem happens :

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 53

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 53

Notice: Undefined offset: 1 in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 53

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 53

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 54

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 54

Notice: Undefined offset: 2 in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 54

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 54

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 55

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 55

Notice: Undefined offset: 3 in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 55

Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null in /home/cphdigit/b2b.cph-hydro.com/wp-content/themes/cph-hydro/inc/elementor/class-elementor.php on line 55

Comment: Please show supporting (code, screenshots, etc.) of what you're trying to accomplish.

Comment: It's just an error [link] https://prntscr.com/10fypei [link] appears on the top of the page